# How to annotate multiple datasets in ListPlots

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Frequently I have to visualize multiple datasets simultaneously, usually in ListPlot or its Log-companions. Since the number of datasets is usually larger than the number of easily distinguishable line styles and creating large plot legends is still somewhat unintuitiv I am still searching for a good way to annotate the different lines/sets in my plots. Tooltip is nice when working on screen, but they don't help if I need to pritn the plot.

Recently, I played around with the Mesh option to enumerate my datasets and found some weird stuff

```
GraphicsGrid[Partition[Table[ListPlot[
Transpose@
 Table[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x], Cot[x]}, {x, 0.01, 10, 0.1}], 
PlotMarkers -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, Mesh -> i, Joined -> True, 
PlotLabel -> "Mesh\[Rule]" <> ToString[i], ImageSize -> 180], {i, 
1, 30}], 4]]
```

The result looks like this on my machine (Windows 7 x64, Mathematica 8.0.1):

[image: Mesh = i, with i running from 1 to 30]

Funnily, for Mesh->2, 8 , and 10 the result looks like I expected it, the rest does not. Either I don't understand the Mesh option, or it doesn't understand me.

Here are my questions:

1. is Mesh in ListPLot bugged or do I use it wrongly?
2. how could I x-shift the mesh points of successive sets to avoid overprinting?
3. do you have any other suggestions how to annotate/enumerate multiple datasets in a plot?

Comment: The problem of the interplay between `Mesh` and `PlotMarkers` came up in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789047/custom-intervals-of-markers-in-mathematica-plotmarkers/4790805#4790805). I reported it to WRI at the time and tech support forwarded it onto the development group to look at. Hopefully it will be fixed in the next release.

Comment: I am curious why some Mesh options work while many others don't.

Comment: As to your third question, you might want to look at the graph I used here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745298/how-do-i-access-the-stackoverflow-api-from-mathematica/5745783#5745783. This involves manual annotations (which can be made to work semi-automatically). I feel the end result is visually much more pleasing than many other methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try something along these lines.  Make each line into a button which, when clicked, identifies itself.

```
plot=Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x]},{x,0,2*Pi}];
sinline=plot[[1,1,3,2]];
cosline=plot[[1,1,4,2]];
message="";
altplot=Append[plot,PlotLabel->Dynamic[message]];
altplot[[1,1,3,2]]=Button[sinline,message="Clicked on the Sin line"];
altplot[[1,1,4,2]]=Button[cosline,message="Clicked on the Cos line"];
altplot
```

If you add an EventHandler you can get the location where you clicked and add an Inset with the relevant positioned label to the plot. Wrap the plot in a Dynamic so it updates itself after each button click.  It works fine.

In response to comments, here is a fuller version:

```
plot = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}];
sinline = plot[[1, 1, 3, 2]];
cosline = plot[[1, 1, 4, 2]];
AddLabel[label_] := (AppendTo[plot[[1]],
    Inset[Framed[label, Background -> White], pt]];
   (* Remove buttons for final plot *)
   plainplot = plot;
   plainplot[[1, 1, 3, 2]] = plainplot[[1, 1, 3, 2, 1]];
   plainplot[[1, 1, 4, 2]] = plainplot[[1, 1, 4, 2, 1]]);
plot[[1, 1, 3, 2]] = Button[sinline, AddLabel["Sin"]];
plot[[1, 1, 4, 2]] = Button[cosline, AddLabel["Cos"]];
Dynamic[EventHandler[plot,
  "MouseDown" :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"])]]
```

To add a label click on the line.  The final annotated chart, set to 'plainplot', is printable and copyable, and contains no dynamic elements.

[Later in the day] Another version, this time generic, and based on the initial chart. (With parts of Mark McClure's solution used.)  For different plots 'ff' and 'spec' can be edited as desired.

```
ff = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot};
spec = Range[0.1, 10, 0.1];
(* Plot functions separately to obtain line counts *)
plots = Array[ListLinePlot[ff[[#]] /@ spec] &, Length@ff];
plots = DeleteCases[plots, Line[_?(Length[#] < 3 &)], Infinity];
numlines = Array[Length@Cases[plots[[#]], Line[_], Infinity] &,
   Length@ff];
(* Plot functions together for annotation plot *)
plot = ListLinePlot[#@spec & /@ ff];
plot = DeleteCases[plot, Line[_?(Length[#] < 3 &)], Infinity];
lbl = Flatten@Array[ConstantArray[ToString@ff[[#]],
      numlines[[#]]] &, Length@ff];
(* Line positions to substitute with buttons *)
linepos = Position[plot, Line, Infinity];
Clear[line];
(* Copy all the lines to line[n] *)
Array[(line[#] = plot[[Sequence @@ Most@linepos[[#]]]]) &,
  Total@numlines];
(* Button function *)
AddLabel[label_] := (AppendTo[plot[[1]],
    Inset[Framed[label, Background -> White], pt]];
   (* Remove buttons for final plain plot *)
   plainplot = plot;
   bpos = Position[plainplot, Button, Infinity];
   Array[(plainplot[[Sequence @@ Most@bpos[[#]]]] =
       plainplot[[Sequence @@ Append[Most@bpos[[#]], 1]]]) &,
    Length@bpos]);
(* Substitute all the lines with line buttons *)
Array[(plot[[Sequence @@ Most@linepos[[#]]]] = Button[line[#],
      AddLabel[lbl[[#]]]]) &, Total@numlines];
Dynamic[EventHandler[plot,
  "MouseDown" :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"])]]
```

Here's how it looks.  After annotation the plain graphics object can be found set to the 'plainplot' variable.

[image: Annotated Chart]

Comment: Very interesting idea for presentation! It is a nice alternative for tooltips (especially if the line will be highlighted in some way, for example will be made bold - and we need not to click it, just put the mouse over it!). Thank you. +1

Comment: Very nice idea, however, it is similar to Tooltip, which tends to be useless if you need the plot printed. For presentation though, thast is a nice way.

Comment: @ Markus - I have added a fuller example which shows the labels stick after they are placed, so the annotated plot can be printed.

Comment: Just an illustration for my first comment here: [working example of such functionality for Graphics3D](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/9a53fae615288733).

Answer (score 8):

One approach is to generate the plots separately and then show them together.  This yields code that is more like yours than the other post, since `PlotMarkers` seems to play the way we expect when dealing with one data set.  We can get the same coloring using `ColorData` with `PlotStyle`.  Here's the result:

```
ff = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot};
plots = Table[ListLinePlot[ff[[i]] /@ Range[0.1, 10, 0.1],
    PlotStyle -> {ColorData[1, i]},
    PlotMarkers -> i, Mesh -> 22], {i, 1, Length[ff]}];
(* Delete the spurious asymptote looking thingies. *)
plots = DeleteCases[plots, Line[ll_?(Length[#] < 4 &)], Infinity];
Show[plots, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, this is the method I use, as sometimes you need to track several additional dimensions using symbols and colors, and nothing works quite as well.

Comment: I was aware that splitting the example above into separate individual plots is a workaround - maybe that is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Are you going to be plotting computable curves or actual data?

If it's computable curves, then it's common to use a [plot legend (key)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/PlotLegends/tutorial/PlotLegends.html).
You can use different dashings and thicknesses to differentiate between the lines on a grayscale printer. There are many examples in the PlotLegends documentation.

If it's real data, then normally the data is sparse enough that you can use `PlotMarkers` for the actual data points (i.e. don't specify `Mesh`). You can use automatic `PlotMarkers`, or you can use custom `PlotMarkers` including [`BoxWhisker`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) markers to indicate the various uncertainties.

Comment: This would indeed be the standard way of doing this. However, the PlotLegend package is seriously flawed (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463437/plotting-legends-in-mathematica/3533152#3533152) and besides, I feel it has aesthetic issues.

Comment: @Sjoerd: I hadn't noticed that question. The way that `PlotLegend` rescales the `Plot` is not good...