# How to avoid asymptotes when I ListPlot a table of data using Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am plotting a table of data using ListPlot in Mathematica. I notice that there are a few asymptotes on the graph which I do not want it to be plotted (i.e. the straight lines between the curves). What should I do to remove the straight lines?

Comment: Can you give an example dataset you're plotting?

Comment: Are you sure that you're talking about asymptotes? I have the impression that you're talking about gaps in your data. Asymptotes aeren't "straight lines between curves"

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4382610/499167) SO question is of interest?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

```
t = Table[Tan[i], {i, -Pi, Pi, .01}];
ListPlot[#, Joined -> True] & /@ {t, t /. x_ /; Abs@x > 10 -> None}
```

[image]

**Edit**

More robust:

```
t = Table[Tan[i], {i, -Pi, Pi, .01}];
ao = AbsoluteOptions[ListPlot[t, Joined -> True],PlotRange]/. {_ -> {_,x_}} ->x;
ListPlot[t /. x_ /; (x < ao[[1]] || x > ao[[2]]) -> None,  Joined -> True]
```

Answer (score 3):

A method from Mark McClure's post here: [How to annotate multiple datasets in ListPlots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988983/how-to-annotate-multiple-datasets-in-listplots/6989666#6989666)

```
t = Table[Tan[i], {i, -Pi, Pi, .01}];
plot = ListLinePlot[t];
DeleteCases[plot, Line[_?(Length[#] < 4 &)], Infinity]
```

Comment: The OP asked for ListPlot, not ListLinePlot

Comment: @belisarius: ["ListLinePlot is a special case of ListPlot"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLinePlot.html#528126457)

Comment: @Simon May be, but the posted solution does not work with ListPlot in _my_ machine

Answer (score 0):

```
t = Table[Tan[i], {i, -Pi, Pi, .01}];
plot = ListLinePlot[t];
```

Using `Position`

```
Position[plot, Line[___], Infinity]
```

{{1, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 3, 4}, {1, 1, 3, 5}, {1, 1, 3, 6}}

Using `Part`:

```
plot[[1, 1, 3, 5 ;; 6]] = Sequence[]; Show[plot]
```