# labeling different plots in the same graph in Mathematica 8

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I have a question with labeling a plot in *Mathematica*. I will describe my problem.

I have a function like this.

```
y = 4 x / L + 2
```

I want to draw a graph of y vs. x. And also,I have

```
L={10,20,30,40}
```

When I write a code like below,

```
Plot[y, {x, 0, 100}, 
    ImageSize -> Scaled[1.0], PlotLabel ->  Style["y vs X ", FontSize -> 18]]
```

I have four different plots in the same graph. I want to know how to label each plot with their relavant L value.

Comment: Please read the manual to get a basic grip on the syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can label the lines as you like using this method, based on my earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6989817/879601).  After labelling, the plot without dynamic content can be found set to `plainplot`.

It works by turning each line into a self-labelling button.  You can modify `labels` for different labels.

```
l = {10, 20, 30, 40};
y[x_, s_] := 4 x/s + 2

plot = Plot[Evaluate@Table[y[x, u], {u, l}], {x, 0, 100},
   PlotLabel -> Style["y vs X ", FontSize -> 18]];

pos = Position[plot, _Line];
Array[(line[#] = plot[[Sequence @@ pos[[#]]]]) &, Length@l];
AddLabel[label_] := Module[{},
  AppendTo[plot[[1]], Inset[Framed[label, Background -> White], pt]];
  (* Removing buttons for final plot *)
  plainplot = plot;
  Array[
   (plainplot[[Sequence @@ pos[[#]]]] =
      plainplot[[Sequence @@ Append[pos[[#]], 1]]]) &, Length@l]]
labels = ToString /@ l;
Array[
  (plot[[Sequence @@ pos[[#]]]] =
     Button[line[#], AddLabel[labels[[#]]]]) &, Length@l];
Dynamic[EventHandler[plot,
  "MouseDown" :> (pt = MousePosition["Graphics"])]]
```

[image]

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4028/193 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4444/labeling-individual-curves-in-mathematica and

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Wizard. Could you please tell me how to label them like "l=10",....and I want to remove these small boxes. I am beginner in Mathematica. Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @Thakshila - You could change the `Inset` to `Inset[Framed["l = " <> ToString[label], Background -> White, FrameStyle -> None], pt]` or (to move the labels by a uniform displacement) `Inset["l = " <> ToString[label] <> "     \n", pt]`

Comment: @ChrisDegnen When I run this code, it doesn't come out with any label. Could you explain the reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

```
l = {10, 20, 30, 40}
y[x_, s_] := 4 x/s + 2
<< PlotLegends`

Plot[Evaluate@Table[y[x, u], {u, l}], {x, 0, 100}, 
 ImageSize -> Scaled[1.0], 
 PlotLabel -> Style["y vs X ", FontSize -> 18], 
 PlotLegend -> ("L = " <> ToString@# & /@ l)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you belisarius. When I print this plot, others cannot see the color.That's the problem.